# Else statement executes before all of the text file has been processed

Tags: java

I'm a new programmer.

I am programming a login system that can validate usernames and passwords through file processing.

I have this issue, where my login system can validate the first pair of credentials in my credentials.txt, but it doesn't get the chance to validate the second pair, as the 'else' statement executes, if the first two credentials aren't a match.

All help will be appreciated.

```
public void verifyLogin(String username, String password) throws FileNotFoundException {

    try {
        File readCredentials = new File("credentials.txt");

        Scanner readFile = new Scanner(readCredentials);

        boolean matchFound = false;

        while (readFile.hasNextLine() && matchFound == false) {

            uIUsername = readFile.nextLine();
            uIPassword = readFile.nextLine();

            if (uIUsername.equals(username) && uIPassword.equals(password)) {

                System.out.println("You are logged in");

                readFile.close();

                matchFound = true;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Error");

                readFile.close();

                matchFound = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't close the Scanner in the while loop, close it outside if you want to continue it. Also, just say !matchFound instead of matchFound == false

Comment: This is because of the `else` statement. You check the first credentials, and if they don't match, the `else` runs. If your file contains many users, you can't use `else`. Instead move that code after the loop. That said, I hope this is just a toy project. In real life, never store passwords, only store (salted) hashes of passwords, so that an attacker cannot steal your password database.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

No worries, this is just a toy project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to print the error message once the loop has finished. Do it as follows:

```
public void verifyLogin(String username, String password) {
    Scanner readFile;
    try {
        File readCredentials = new File("credentials.txt");
        readFile = new Scanner(readCredentials);
        boolean matchFound = false;
        while (readFile.hasNextLine() && matchFound == false) {
            uIUsername = readFile.nextLine();
            uIPassword = readFile.nextLine();
            if (uIUsername.equals(username) && uIPassword.equals(password)) {
                System.out.println("You are logged in");
                matchFound = true;
            }
        }
        if (!matchFound) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    readFile.close();
}
```

Note that I have also placed `readFile.close()` only once instead of repeating it in both, `if` and `else` part.

Also, note that I have used `e.printStackTrace()` which will make sure the complete stacktrace will be printed in case of any exception.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it totally works now. 

Also thank you for the additional tips :-)